# Fill values monthly

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have data with the following structure in BigQuery:

```sql
select 
    1 as user_id, date('2021-01-01') as transaction_date, 1 as value
union all (select 1, '2021-01-02', 2)
union all (select 1, '2021-01-05', 2)
union all (select 1, '2021-02-01', 2)
union all (select 1, '2021-02-03', 2)
union all (select 2, '2021-01-02', 2)
union all (select 2, '2021-02-01', 2)
union all (select 2, '2021-02-03', 3)
```

I want, for every user and month, to fill in the missing values between the first and last days of the month that we have data in. The output for this pair of users should be:

```
1,2021-01-01,1
1,2021-01-02,2
1,2021-01-03,null
1,2021-01-04,null
1,2021-01-05,2
1,2021-02-01,2
1,2021-02-02,null
1,2021-02-03,2
2,2021-01-02,2
2,2021-02-01,2
2,2021-02-02,null
2,2021-02-03,3
```

What's the simplest way to do this in bigquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be using `GENERATE_ARRAY()` and `UNNEST` to make a template, and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`ing the template with the original data.

###### query

```
WITH org_data AS (
    select 1 as user_id, date('2021-01-01') as transaction_date, 1 as value
    union all (select 1, '2021-01-02', 2) union all (select 1, '2021-01-05', 2)
    union all (select 1, '2021-02-01', 2) union all (select 1, '2021-02-03', 2)
    union all (select 2, '2021-01-02', 2) union all (select 2, '2021-02-01', 2)
    union all (select 2, '2021-02-03', 3)
),
candidate_user_month AS (
    SELECT
        user_id,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM transaction_date) AS transaction_year,
        EXTRACT(MONTH FROM transaction_date) AS transaction_month,
        COUNT(1) as date_count,
        MIN(EXTRACT(DAY FROM transaction_date)) as min_day,
        MAX(EXTRACT(DAY FROM transaction_date)) as max_day,
    FROM org_data
    GROUP BY user_id, transaction_year, transaction_month
    HAVING date_count >= 2
),
template AS (
    WITH
    date_array AS (
        SELECT
            user_id, transaction_year, transaction_month,
            GENERATE_ARRAY(min_day, max_day, 1) as dates,
        FROM candidate_user_month
    )
    SELECT
        user_id,
        DATE(transaction_year, transaction_month, dates) as transaction_date,
        NULL as value_with_null,
    FROM date_array, UNNEST(dates) as dates
)
SELECT user_id, transaction_date, value,
FROM template
FULL OUTER JOIN org_data USING (user_id, transaction_date)
ORDER BY user_id, transaction_date
;
```

###### results

[image]